# Android Studio error after installing

Tags: android, android-studio, zip, gradle

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and after installing android studio and initializing project it is showing error 
failed to load zip file
Gradle dependencies cache may be corrupt
clicking on the blue link is doing nothing giving same message again that cannot load zip file

[image: this is the error]

Comment: Can you paste contents of gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: i deleted the cache fron .gradle and it worked after re-downloading its content

Answer (score 0):

Go to home directory, then click Ctrl+H and search for .gradle directory

1. .gradle>wrapper>dists
2. You will find the all gradle files
3. Remove that gradle file which is causing the problem and go to Android studio
   and Try Again.
4. It will start downloading that file.
5. If that does not work download that gradle file manually from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/
6. Extract it and replace the file which one is in dists directory.